# Pass context to included Jinja Template in Jinja Template

Tags: flask, jinja2

I have common things in all Jinja files. I want to move all common content to one single Jinja file in Flask.

My app is written in `Flask` and I am passing context to Jinja template like

`def f1(name): render_template('j1.jinja', name=name)`

`def f2(name): render_template('j2.jinja', name=name)`

`def f3(name): render_template('j3.jinja', name=name)`

My `j1.jinja` file is:

```
{%block content %}
Name: {{ name }}
Hello
{% endblock %}
```

My `j2.jinja` file is:

```
{%block content %}
Name: {{ name }}
Bye
{% endblock %}
```

My `j3.jinja` file is:

```
{%block content %}
Name: {{ name }}
Howdy
{% endblock %}
```

I moved common content to single Jinja file `common.jinja` which is:

```
{% block content %}
Name : {{name}}
{% endblock %}
```

I am including it in all Jinja files like:

```
{% include 'common.jinja' with { "name": name } only %}
```

which doesn't work. I am getting the Exception:

```
Exception Occured. Explanation: expected token 'end of statement block', got 'with'
```

How can I pass context to included Jinja file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks a bit weird. There is no separate `with` statement that specifies context, it is `with context` which is often used with `import` statement (see [Import context behaviour](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#import-context-behavior)).

To pass any context to an included template, simply render the parent template with context variables, e.g. in `render_template()`:

```
render_template('j3.jinja', name=name)
```